# css + html full screen background issue

Tags: html, css

I'm new to css & html.

I have a page which scrolls it's background.

And I can't seem to make the background image static, so that the image would stay always on screen and something brown from background would not come up when scrolling down.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Turns out body size was too small. Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: The background image is alright. It's your body element that's too short and being scrolled.

Comment: So increasing body height should solve the issue?

Comment: Exactly, or just remove the restriction of 100% height to make it adaptable.

Comment: Worked like a charm :) Thanks :) If you want, you can write an answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the

```
height: 100%;
```

from your body. That way the body spans the complete content and won't end abruptly.

EDIT: Actually, you should keep it but change it to `min-height`, that way it also works for content smaller than screen height.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that your `body` is smaller than your `div.site-wrapper` set `div.site-wrapper-inner{background: url(images/3.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;}` and remove the background from the body and it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Or remove this

```
    background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
```

Sothat `html` not overlaps `body` with the color

Answer (score 0):

remove line 20 from styles.css - background-color: #333;